# Two classes have the same XML type name.Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, java-11, xjc

I have 2 classes in .xsd format that have same name .
Even though each one of them is under different namespace :

When i try too initialize JAXBContext i get : 
Two classes have the same XML type name "picture". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
Info: Running on java 11. and generate classes with xjc.
This was previously working on java 8

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://test.com/bla/blabla/blablabla/sd" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="picture">






<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://test.com/bla/blabla/blablabla/hd" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="picture">
```

ANd both generated classes look like this:

@XmlRootElement(name = "picutre")
public class Picture { }

I initialize JAXBContext:

```
 private static JAXBContext initializeJaxbContext() {
    JAXBContext jaxbctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(com.test.bla.blabla.blablabla.hd.Picture.class,com.test.bla.blabla.blablabla.sd.Picture.class);
```

Why do i get this error? 
Two classes have the same XML type name.Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that jaxb runtime was inside a war file as transitive dependency of an other package.
The solution was to exclude this in gradle file and have all jaxb dependencies under tomcat lib folder.